# How to use Numpy Matrix operation to calculate multiple samples at once?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

How do I use Numpy matrix operations to calculate over multiple vector samples at once?

Please see below the code I came up with, 'd' is the outcome I'm trying to get. But this is only one sample. How do I calculate the output without doing something like repeat the code for every sample OR looping through every sample?

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
c = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
d = ((a.T * b).flatten() * c.T)

a1 = np.array([[2, 3, 4]])
b1 = np.array([[2, 3, 4]])
c1 = np.array([[2, 3, 4]])
d1 = ((a1.T * b1).flatten() * c1.T)

a2 = np.array([[3, 4, 5]])
b2 = np.array([[3, 4, 5]])
c2 = np.array([[3, 4, 5]])
d2 = ((a2.T * b2).flatten() * c2.T)
```

Comment: `((a.T * b).flatten() * c.T)` you should shorten your code .,..

Comment: @Wen thanks, btw, do you know any solutions to my question?

Comment: Are they always same value for abc or a1b1c1 ? \

Comment: Different values. the above code represent 3 observations. (abc, a1b1c1, a2b2c2). I'm trying to find a more efficient way so when there're thousands of observations, I don't need to repeat the codes thousands of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way broadcasting works is to repeat your data along an axis of size one as many times as necessary to make your element-wise operation work. That is what is happening to axis 1 of `a.T` and axis 0 of `b`. Similar for the product of the result. My recommendation would be to concatenate all your inputs along another dimension, to allow broadcasting to happen along the existing two.

Before showing how to do that, let me just mention that you would be much better off using [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) instead of [`flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) in your example. `flatten` makes a copy of the data, while `ravel` only makes a view. Since `a.T * b` is a temporary matrix anyway, there is really no reason to make the copy.

The easiest way to combine some arrays along a new dimension is [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). I would recommend combining along the first dimension for a couple of reasons. It's the default for `stack` and your result can be indexed more easily: `d[0]` will be `d`, `d[1]` will be `d1`, etc. If you ever add matrix multiplication into your pipeline, [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) will work out of the box since it operates on the last two dimensions.

```
a = np.stack((a0, a1, a2, ..., aN))
b = np.stack((b0, b1, b2, ..., bN))
c = np.stack((c0, c1, c2, ..., cN))
```

Now `a`, `b` and `c` are all 3D arrays the first dimension is the measurement index. The second and third correspond to the two dimensions of the original arrays.

With this structure, what you called transpose before is just swapping the last two dimensions (since one of them is 1), and raveling/flattening is just multiplying out the last two dimensions, e.g. with [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
d = (a.reshape(N, -1, 1) * b).reshape(N, 1, -1) * c.reshape(N, -1, 1)
```

If you set one of the dimensions to have size `-1` in the reshape, it will absorb the remaining size. In this case, all your arrays have 3 elements, so the -1 will be equivalent to 3.

You have to be a little careful when you convert the `ravel` operation to 3D. In 2D, `x.ravel() * c.T` implicitly transforms `x` into a 1xN array before broadcasting. In 3D, `x.reshape(3, -1)` creates a 2D 3x27 array, which you multiply by `c.reshape(3, -1, 1)`, which is 3x3x1. Broadcasting rules state that you are effectively multiplying a 1x3x27 array by a 3x3x1, but you really want to multiply a 3x1x27 array by the 3x3x1, so you need to specify all three axes for the 3D "ravel" explicitly.

Here is an IDEOne link with your sample data for you to play with: https://ideone.com/p8vTlx

Comment: thanks for the answer, what does `a.reshape(3,-1,1)` do? Is it turning it into a 3D object? Is the 3 the number of rows? How about -1 and 1 ? Cheers.

Comment: @theman. See update. Also, read up on the links to the functions. The docs should clarify a lot of things.

Comment: @theman. I also fixed an error I had in the final expression. The second reshape has to explicitly have 3 axes, not 2.